# Use javascript promises in ios ionic app

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, promise

I need to use the following promises in ionic (ios apparently it's fine on android):

```
var Attendees = Parse.Object.extend("Attendees");

    return Promise.all(eventDetails.map(detail => {
        return Promise.all([new Promise((res, rej) => {
            var query2 = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
            query2.equalTo("event_id", detail .id_event);    
            query2.count({
                success: function(number) {
                    detail["n_requests_received"] =  number;
                    alert("received")
                    res('Some value if required'); //These are needed or promise chain will hang
                }
            });
        }),
        new Promise((res, rej) => {
            var query3 = new Parse.Query(Attendees);
            query3.equalTo("event_id", detail .id_event);
            query3.equalTo("status", "confirmed")
            query3.count({
                success: function(number) {
                    detail["n_requests_confirmed"] =  number;
                   // alert("confirmed")
                   res('Some value if required'); //These are needed or promise chain will hang
                }
            });
        })]);
    }));
```

do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using deferred so that you can run a promise chain instead of keeping them separate. You'll also need to handle the error case (same error function used for both promises) if something wrong happens with the call. It will reject the promise properly for you to handle appropriately.

```
var promises = [];

eventDetails.forEach(function(detail) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    new Parse.Query('Attendees')
    .equalTo("event_id", detail.id_event) 
    .count().then(function(number) {
        detail["n_requests_received"] =  number;
        alert("received");
        return new Parse.Query('Attendees')
        .equalTo("event_id", detail .id_event)
        .equalTo("status", "confirmed")
        .count();
    }).then(function(confirmedCount) {
        detail["n_requests_confirmed"] = confirmedCount;
        deferred.resolve('I have resolved this promise');
    }, function(err) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
        deferred.reject('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    });

    promises.push(deferred.promise());
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(res) {
    // completed all promises w/ no errors
}, function(err) {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Comment: not working. I think the => is a ES6 symbol so is not recognized in ionic. Do you know how to replace the =< in the first row with a then?

Comment: Edited my answer. I thought you had this somewhat working in Ionic and using ES7. It doesn't use regular promises like that, you must use $q Angular style for promises.